# IllegalArgumentException with Date value in jdbc; Openbase sql

Tags: jdbc, webobjects, openbase

I have a WebObjects app, Openbase db, and I'm getting a never before seen exception when doing a raw rows (non ORM) query during a batch operation. It looks like the jdbc adaptor is throwing on a date value in the db and is unable to coerce the raw data into the proper type. It literally kills the app and ends the export process. Here's the top two relevant lines from the trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at java.sql.Date.valueOf(Date.java:138)
 at com.openbase.jdbc.f.getDate(Unknown Source)
```

I've tried changing the column type from date, to datetime to timestamp, and adjusting the eo model accordingly, but the exception remains. I'm wondering what I can do to resolve this, specifically if anybody knows a more sophisticated query mechanism I can employ to identify the possibly bad rows? Openbase's documentation is pretty sparse, and I'm hoping maybe somebody knows how to use patterns to identify possible bad values using openbase sql. Or, some other means of identifying the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I just found, by painful small set querying, a load of rows that have a date format like '-001-12-31 12:00:00 -0500' I found this highly suspect, so I did a simple test and there were no errors; openbase and jdbc adaptor didn't complain about these rows at all. Furthermore, using like '-001%' per the docs doesn't work. Maybe like doesn't work with timestamps in openbase. Maddeningly stumped...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was due to a version mismatch between the Openbase version and the java version. Unfortunately, I had no choice but to rewrite the dump routine to use the bulk save openbase function, and then parse out the resulting csv. Interestingly, the same dates that were causing problems printed just fine, which enabled saving a lot more rows. Summary: stick with the open source db's; unless you're going high end, there's no advantage to solutions like Openbase anymore.